# Execute variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, eval

I have a code in javascript which according to some data from a json I run a function passing the json parameters and an object that runs it. I'm new to javascript and as I've read you can do with eval (although you should avoid it) but it shows me an error with the object.

So I put my question here, because after several hours and variations of code (trial and error) I can not make it work.

My code is as follows (summary code for not much longer):

```
var objMain = { 

    uniqueid: function(cb) {
        ............
    },
    control: function (data, cb){
        ............  
    },
    change: function(res, value) {

        res.optimize(value);
    }
};

.........
.........

    console.log(result);
    // output: { type: 'change', data: '37878788266AF38' }

    //eval( objMain.result['type'](result.data) );

    //eval( 'objMain.' + result['type'] + '(' + res + ', \'' + result.data + '\')' );

    var obj = {

        "res": res,
        "data": result.data
    };

    eval( 'objMain.' + result['type'] + '(' + obj + ')' ); // Slope of change the function call, when it works...

    // Output error-> objMain.change([object Object])
```

Is there any way to run a function as the value of a variable/property, passing it a parameter object? Thansk

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `eval()`.

Instead, just call the function by name:

```
objMain[result.type](result.data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need or want `eval` for this, if I'm reading right that `result.type` will have one of those function names in it.

Just use brackets notation:

```
objMain[result.type](obj);
```

In JavaScript, you can access an object property either with dot notation using a *literal* property name (`obj.foo`), or with brackets notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`). With brackets notation, the property name string can come from any expression, including a property lookup on another object.

Answer (score 1):

```
objMain[result.type](result.data)
```